# How to put button inside an input field?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I tried to figure out how to put a button into an input field but I can't find a solution.
I want to have it looks like this

[image]

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap for the input field and the Angular Material button.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg mb-4 mt-4">            
       <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Suche starten">
          <button mat-mini-fab>
                <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
          </button>
</div>
```

I also tried to wrap the button into a `input-group-prepend` div but it also did not work.
I also tried with `mat-form-field` from Angular material but same like above, I cannot put this button into this input field.

Also asked google and but couldn't find any solutions...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use CSS to absolutely position the button inside the input-group.

Comment: You just need use some css to move button to the right an make border-radius: 0 for right corners of input

Comment: `input-group-prepend` would put the button on the left side of the input. `input-group-append` puts it on the right. Then try adding `input-group-text` class to the button itself.